# How to call this Delphi function from a DLL in C#?

Tags: c#, function, delphi, dll, char

I am given a Delphi DLL that contains functions that I need to call in C#. One of the functions takes two char arrays, where one is an encrypted password and the other is the key.

```
TCString = array[0..254] of Char;
...
function Decrypt(const S, Key: TCString): TCString; stdcall;
```

I tried to figure out how to call this function on my own but I keep getting "Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination." I am using byte since the Char type in Delphi is AnsiChar which is 8 bits.

```
[DllImport("path", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern byte[] Decrypt(byte[] S, byte[] Key);
```

What is the correct way to call this in C#?

Comment: There are a few ways to deal with this. First step is going to be to work out what Char is in your Delphi. Is it 8 or 16 bits wide? Is assume that it is 8 bits and that the Delphi developer is being sloppy using Char rather than Byte.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The Delphi developer said that the character type he is using is AnsiChar so it is 8 bits

Answer (score 3):

I think I would be inclined to wrap the fixed length array in a C# struct.

```
public struct CString
{
    [UnmanagedType.ByValArray(SizeConst=255)]
    byte[] value;
}
```

This allows the size to be specified in one place only.

The next hurdle is the return value. The Delphi ABI treats a return value that cannot fit into a register as an additional hidden `var` parameter. I'll translate that as a C# `out` parameter.

Finally the two input parameters are declared as `const`. That means that they are passed by reference.

So the function would be:

```
[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void Decrypt(
    [In] ref CString S, 
    [In] ref CString Key, 
    out CString Result
```

);

I've intentionally avoided any use of text in this because this would appear to be a function that operates on binary data. Many Delphi programmers treat `AnsiChar` arrays interchangeably with byte arrays in such situations which is often confusing.

Comment: I did what you suggested. It seems like I progressed a big. But, I am now getting the error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Comment: Yeah, I messed up the two in out parameters. Try the latest edit.

Comment: I tried your method. Now it is able to call the method, but the output is always an array of nulls. Do you think it is the C# code or the Delphi DLL?